# "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\HookManager::getHookOptions()"

Tags: 8, drush

I just installed drush using "composer require drush/drush". It ran correctly and when it completes a navigate to vendor/drush/drush/ directory where the drush.php file is located

Then I run the following command: 
php drush.php status and I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\HookManager::getHookOptions() in 
[...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/includes/annotationcommand_adapter.inc on line 475
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() [...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:0
PHP   2. drush_main() [...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:12
PHP   3. Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch() [...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc:66
PHP   4. drush_dispatch() [...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php:67
PHP   5. annotationcommand_adapter_add_hook_options() [...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc:170
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                      [error]
Error: Call to undefined method Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\HookManager::getHookOptions() in
[...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/drush/drush/includes/annotationcommand_adapter.inc, line 475
```

Can anyone please guide me to what might be causing this?

Additional details:

1. I am on ubuntu 16.04
2. Drupal 8 installation
3. version of drush 8.1

Comment: Could be a permissions issue, could you try to soften the permissions on the vendor/drush folder?

Comment: Did you run "composer global update" after install, then "drush init" ?

Comment: I assume that `[...]/work/www/EnviePractice/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/` exists?

Comment: If you installed Drupal 8.3 you must use drush 8.1.10 as specified in the release note. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think your installation or class registry might be broken. Try doing the following things:

- See if `drush rebuild` works (if it does not, go to the next point).
- Go to your Drupal install directory and try to run `composer install`.
- If `drush rebuild` didn't work in the first step, try running it again now.